# Set of points on which continuous maps agree

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces and $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ are continuous maps. What is a counter-example that shows the set of points on which $f=g$ need not be closed? What general conditions can we impose on $X$ and/or $Y$ to make this set closed?

(For instance, if $Y$ is Hausdorff, then there need be no further condition on $X$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A sufficient condition:**

> Either $Y$ is Hausdorff or $X$ is discrete.

**A necessary condition:**

> Either (i) $Y$ is T$_1$, or (ii) $X$ is discrete, or (iii) $Y$ is T$_0$ and every open set in $X$ is closed.

For suppose the alleged necessary condition is not satisfied. There are two cases, depending on whether $Y$ is or is not T$_0$.

**Case 1.** $Y$ is not T$_1$, and $X$ has an open set which is not closed.

**Case 2.** $Y$ is not T$_0$, and $X$ is not discrete.

In Case 1, choose a set $A\subset X$ which is open but not closed, and choose distinct points $y_1,y_2\in Y$ so that every neighborhood of $y_2$ contains $y_1$. Define $f,g:X\to Y$ so that $f(x)=y_1$ for all $x$, while $g(x)=y_1$ for $x\in A$ and $g(x)=y_2$ for $x\notin A$. Then $f$ and $g$ are continuous maps, and $\{x:f(x)=g(x)\}=A$ is not closed.

In Case 2, choose a set $A\subset X$ which is not closed, and choose distinct points $y_1,y_2\in Y$ which have the same neighborhoods. Define $f$ and $g$ as in Case 1.

Comment: It would be easier to follow if you  separate the "ors" and "ands" more emphatically in your first sentence of the Necessary condition.