# Two continuous maps agree on an open dense set, must they be equal?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $f,g:X\to Y$ are two continuous maps of topological spaces, and $A$ is an open dense subset of $X$, if $f|_A=g|_A$ and $f|_A$ is an open immersion, do we have $f=g$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459097/set-of-points-on-which-continuous-maps-agree?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

No, the property that you need for this to work is Hausdorfness for topological spaces or separatedness for schemes. A counterexample in both categories:

Let $X$ be the affine line with double origin and let $A$ be the complement of one of the origins. Let $f$ be the identity on $X$ and let $g$ be the identity on $A$ and send the second origin to the first one.

Comment: In case of schemes, are $f$ and $g$ separated?

Comment: @Borntobeproud what I mean is separatedness as a property of schemes (that is, the structure morphism being separated). In any case, the identity is always separated, so $f$ is also a separated morphism.

Comment: Suppose $(f,f^\sharp),(g,g^\sharp):(X,\mathcal O_X)\to (Y,\mathcal O_Y)$ are two separated morphisms of schemes, and $A$ is an open dense subset of $X$, if $(f|_A,(f|_A)^\sharp)=(g|_A,(g|_A)^\sharp):(A,(\mathcal O_X)|_A)\to (Y,\mathcal O_Y)$ is an open immersion, how to show $f=g$ as continuous maps on the underlying topological spaces?

Comment: @Borntobeproud you need the schemes to be separated, not the morphisms (although any morphism between separated schemes is separated). Use that the graphs of the two morphisms are closed to deduce what you want. To show that the graphs are closed, find an appropiate pullback diagram and use the fact that the pullback of a closed immersion is again a closed immersion